# I cannot save my Data when separating classes

Tags: flutter, class, dart, generics, sharedpreferences

I try to save CheckBox and RadioListTile data . I separated CheckBox and RadioList as Class . Here is My Codes , I tried a lot but I could not fix problem .

Comment: provide the code sample

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: https://github.com/ekrembulut/Storage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have checked your repository. I think you should add at least the source codes of the 'home.dart', 'chechBox.dart' and 'radioButtons.dart' to your question. So others can understand your problem even if the link you have provided in the comments gets broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your code to reproduce the issue. There are several issues, but no worries:

1- You should make your `Child` widgets(`MyCheckBox`, `MyRadio`) stateless, as their states are handled by the parent(`HomePage`).

2- In `home_page.dart`: `HomePage` calls the `MyCheckBox` widget like following:

`home_page.dart`

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  List<String> fruits = [];
  Helper myHelper = Helper();
  FutureServices future = FutureServices();
  Singers currentSinger = Singers.Ianis;
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    verileriOku1();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build calıştı");
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Storage App")),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "İsim Giriniz"),
              ),
            ),
            MyRadio(),
            MyCheckBox(myValue: (value) {
              value = fruits;
              
            }),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(fruits);
                print(currentSinger);
              },
              child: Text("Yazdır"),
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  var object =
                      MyVariables(_controller.text, currentSinger, fruits);
                  myHelper.verileriKaydet(object);
                },
                child: Text("Kaydet")),
          ],
        ));
  }

  void verileriOku1() async {
    var info = await myHelper.verileriOku();

    setState(() {
      _controller.text = info.name;
      fruits = info.fruitList;
      currentSinger = info.singer;
    });
  }
}
```

As we can see, you are not assigning fruits correctly. So one possible solution could be:

```
MyCheckBox(myValue: (value) {
  fruits = value;        
}),
```

But in the following step, I decided to remove that `Function`. Instead, you will need to provide the list of fruits to the `Child` widget directly.

3- In `my_check_box.dart`: the `MyCheckBox` widget has a required `Function` to communicate with `HomePage` like the following:

`my_check_box.dart`

```
class MyCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function myValue;
  MyCheckBox({Key? key, required this.myValue}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCheckBox> createState() => _MyCheckBoxState();
}
```

So you needed to pass data between those widgets, and you chose to do it with `Function`. But since `List` is passed by reference in `Dart` language, you can use a `List` to pass values:

```
const MyCheckBox({
  Key? key,
  required this.savedFruits,
  required this.onChanged,
}) : super(key: key);

final List<String> savedFruits;
final void Function(bool? value, Meyveler meyve) onChanged;
```

Another positive side of using a `List` is now we can check correctly if these fruits are saved fruits:

`my_check_box.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/enums.dart';

class MyCheckBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCheckBox({
    Key? key,
    required this.savedFruits,
    required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> savedFruits;
  final void Function(bool? value, Meyveler meyve) onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
        children: [
          for (var meyve in Meyveler.values) check(meyve),
        ],
      );

  CheckboxListTile check(Meyveler meyve) => CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(meyve.name),
        value: savedFruits.contains(describeEnum(meyve)),
        onChanged: (value) => onChanged(value, meyve),
      );
}
```

4- When it comes to the `radio buttons`, There is no connection between `HomePage` and `MyRadio` widgets. So take a look please the following solution related to this topic:

`my_radio.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/enums.dart';

class MyRadio extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyRadio({
    Key? key,
    required this.currentSinger,
    required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Singers currentSinger;
  final void Function(Singers singer) onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
        children: [
          for (var singer in Singers.values) _radio(singer),
        ],
      );

  RadioListTile<Singers> _radio(Singers singer) => RadioListTile(
        title: Text(singer.name),
        value: singer,
        groupValue: currentSinger,
        onChanged: (_) => onChanged(singer),
      );
}
```

You can access the modified source code through [GitHub](https://github.com/BBarisKilic/Stack-OverFlow-Solutions/tree/master/question_72479398).

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I solve my problem easily when following your steps :))

Comment: @CoderDuck You're welcome :) If you haven't any further questions, please mark this answer as an `accepted` answer.